# Script and Scriptreplay give me some problems

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu

I want to replicate what I do on my console. 
I'm using this command:

```
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop$ script -t 2> timing.log -a output.session
```

and then I execute some commands but at the moment of replication this occurs:

```
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop$ scriptreplay time.log record.session 
scriptreplay: unexpected end of file on record.session
```

And **record.session** is empty. I don't know what's wrong!!!

I'm on ubuntu 13.04,

thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just I missed the **exit** command.

This is the complete sequence:

1- To start the recording

```
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop$ script -t 2> timing.log -a output.session
```

2- To stop the recording execute **exit**

```
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop$ exit
```

3- and then I execute the next command to see the complete recording:

```
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop$ scriptreplay timing.log output.session
```